# Problems with a nested datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, datalist, nested-datalist

I have a nested DataList structure `DataList2` inside `DataList1` where I have two `Buttons` inside `DataList2` that perform certain commands.

I want to call a procedure that takes as input the `datakeyfield` of `DataList1` and `datakeyfield` of `DataList2`. However there is a problem with reading the `datakeyfield` of `DataList2`. Here is my code:

#### *.aspx.cs* code

```
protected void DataList2_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.CommandName == "accept") && (e.CommandArgument != null))
    {
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        int team_ID = (int)DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex];
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("accept_member", conn);
        string member = (string)DataList2.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex];
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        string email = Session["email"].ToString();
        int course_ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["courseID"]);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@course_ID", course_ID));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@team_ID", team_ID));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@myemail", email));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@member", member));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@respond", 1));
        SqlParameter count = cmd.Parameters.Add("@count", SqlDbType.Int);
        count.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (@count.Value.ToString().Equals("1"))
        {
            Response.Write(@member + " " + "joined your team");

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("team is full or not found");
        }
    }
    else if ((e.CommandName == "reject") && (e.CommandArgument != null))
    {
        int team_ID = (int)DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex];
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        string member = (string)DataList2.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex];
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("accept_member", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        string email = Session["email"].ToString();
        int course_ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["courseID"]);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@course_ID", course_ID));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@team_ID", team_ID));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@myemail", email));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@member", member));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@respond", "0"));
        SqlParameter count = cmd.Parameters.Add("@count", SqlDbType.Int);
        count.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (@count.Value.ToString().Equals("1"))
        {
            Response.Write(@member + " " + "has been rejected");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("team is full or not found");
        }
    }

    DataList2.DataBind();
}
```

#### Error

> The name "DataList2" does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data produces more than one row in DataList1, there is more than one DataList2. ASP.NET therefore doesn't make DataList2 a member of your page (codebehind) class.

Fortunately, in this instance sender (which you called source, same thing) should be the DataList2 that you want. Try casting it to DataList and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a couple of mistakes. First `DataList2` is not directly accessible (as you have noticed). And second you are using the same `ItemIndex` for both the parent and child DataList. But since they are nested they do not have the same values but need to be accesses by a different array index.

```
protected void DataList2_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //cast the source back to a the datalist
    DataList datalist2 = source as DataList;

    //get the value from the nested datalist
    string childValue = (string)datalist2.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex];

    //get the parent object of datalist2
    DataListItem dli = datalist2.NamingContainer as DataListItem;

    //get the value from the parent datalist using the itemindex of the parent, not the child
    int parentValue = (int)DataList1.DataKeys[dli.ItemIndex];

    //show results
    Label1.Text = parentValue + " - " + childValue;

    //rebind datalist2
    datalist2.DataBind();
}
```